# How to create a dashboard using excel and .bat file

Tags: java, excel, batch-file

I would like to ask the community if there is any way to create a GUI menu where the options will populate itself based on number of files that are saved in a folder directory. The user will then have two options whereby he can choose to generate a status or a dashboard option. After he chooses the report that he wish to generate, another menu will appear to ask him which document he want to select. This is where the menu would check the folder and generate the options based on number of files in the folder. For example, there could be doc1 and doc2 in the folder. Then the menu will generate 2 options. 1. Select doc1. 2. Select doc2. Then after the user inserted another doc3 into the folder. The menu will add another 3. Select doc3 without having the user to change the code. Is there a way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your .bat file could launch a particular Excel file, you could go that way, putting all the dashboard info in the spreadsheet.  Would require some VBA code to make it as interactive as it sounds like you want, but that's entirely possible.

I'm not aware of any way that a .bat file can create a GUI on its own, although I may be missing something.  Since the .bat file can run almost anything, it can be a starting point, but the heavy lifting would be done in something else.

Another approach would be to look at AutoHotkey, which can give you a GUI and a fair bit of processing power & interactivity all within the one script.  The URL is http://www.autohotkey.com/ and that site has a tremendous amount of examples and help available.  Also some AHK questions here on Stack Overflow from time to time.

Either way you go, it's a fairly large project.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This makes no sense. A `.bat` file is by definition something that does not have a GUI.

Also you really have provided the vaguest information for something seemingly large, and there appears to be no reason why you've also tagged this as `excel` and `exe`.